# How to handle multiple error code scenario in http request

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, observable

**Error codes below :-**

400 - perform `single` retry on response arrival `without delay`

502, 503 and 504 perform `eight` number of retries with `1000 Sec delay`

**My code is below :-**

```
private _getData('loginKey', body, headers) {
return this._http.post('url', body, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .retryWhen(errors => {
    return errors
      .mergeMap((error) => this.handleError(error))
      .delay(2000)
      .take(8);
  });
}

public handleError(error: Response | any): Observable<any> {
  if (error.status === 400) { // retry 1 time and with no delay
    return Observable.of(error);
  } else { // retry confgured times and configured delay
    return Observable.of(error);
  }
}
```

My problem is how to change `delay` and `take` value according to the above Error codes:

if `error.status` is **400** then `delay value 0` and `take value 1`

if `error.status` is **502, 503 and 504** then `delay value 2000` and `take value 8`

Comment: If my response answers your question would you accept it?

Comment: yes definitely if it will helpful.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to define a function in a service that will return the value you want.

example:

```
let errorStatus;
private _getData('loginKey', body, headers) {
return this._http.post('url', body, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .retryWhen(errors => {
    return errors
      .mergeMap((error) => {
          errorStatus = error.status;
          this.handleError(error))
      })
      .delay(ResponseService.getDelay(errorStatus))
      .take(ResponseService.getRetries(errorStatus));
  });
}
```

in ResponseService.js...

```
function getDelay(status) {
    let val = 0;
    switch(status) {
        case 400:
            val = 0;
            break;
        ...
    }
    return val;
}

function getRetries(status) {
    let val = 0;
    switch(status) {
        case 400:
            val = 1;
            break;
        ...
    }
    return val
}
```

Comment: but `error.status` is not accessible in `delay` and `take`

any idea about how to access it.

Comment: I updated the work.  You should be able to capture the value of the error so you can use it outside the scope of the mergeMap

Comment: I have try your solution but still not able to access `errorstatus` inside `delay` and `take` because this is calling before the `mergeMap` inside code run. So any solution on this code or any alternation solution available. **Please see this link:** 
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

i don't have the complete knowledge of `Observable uses` I have used one method from this link `mergeMap`, `delay` and `take` so maybe any alternation solution is available on this link. Please guide me what approach i use for this solution if you know.